# Can I roam around the City at Midnight just to spend the time?

Tags: traffic, police, india, vehicle, indian-penal-code

Do I have the rights to roam or drive my motorcycle around my city in India at midnight just to pass the time?

I am from Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu in India.

Comment: The answer to this question may depend on what city or state you're in; curfew laws are often imposed locally rather than nationally.

Comment: It's better to record if you do. You'll likely be abused by police. This happened to me. I think you need ID proof.

Comment: myself from coimbatore,you could roam around you just need a valid id proof with u and u should clear about your destination

Comment: Having a valid Driving License, Insurance Papers and wearing helmet (as you will drive a bike) and following traffic signals, you are free to drive any where (except non restricted area) you'll have no issues. **Noise and Pollution released by your vehicle should not cross the limits**...